# KIO error connecting to localhost: access denied

Tags: php, linux, xdebug, netbeans-8, kde-plasma

I have Kubuntu 16.10 with KDE5. Also I have php5-cli and php5-xdebug configured to listen localhost on port 9000. But when I run "debug" in the Netbeans, I got error "KIO error: Error connecting to localhost: access denied" raised in small window, and debugging doesn't work.

Comment: Crosspost: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=225&t=130142 -- Is your issue solved?

Comment: Yes, thank you. In project's properties address was localhost:8000, and he tries to connect to empty port, but i'm still confused about KIO here. Isn't he must open browser and pass request?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone getting the same error message with visual studio code: to fix it go to `Settings > Applications > Default Applications`, under Web Browser, tell KDE to use your default browser `in the following application` dropdown menu (firefox in my case). After a reboot it started working